# I am following a Youtube tutorial of django and react but there is an import error in material-ui library that I can't fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the error is :

```
export 'FormHelperText' (imported as 'FormHelperText') was not found in '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText' (possible exports: default).
```

I tried to import in many ways,I deleted and installed the @material-ui/core in my node_modules and it did not work,when it fixes the problem in a import,it creates other problem in another import

````
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid"
import Typography  from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import  TextField  from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import { FormHelperText} from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText'
import {FormControl} from '@material-ui/core/FormControl'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import  {Radio}  from '@material-ui/core/Radio'
import  {RadioGroup}  from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup'
import  {FormControlLabel}  from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel'
export default class CreateRoomPage extends Component{
    defaultVotes=2
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
           guestCanPause:true,
           votesToSkip:this.defaultVotes

       }
       this.handleRoomButtonPressed=this.handleRoomButtonPressed.bind(this) 
       this.handleVotesChange=this.handleVotesChange.bind(this)
       this.handleGuestCanPauseChange=this.handleGuestCanPauseChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleVotesChange(e){ //e é o objt q chm essa fnç
        this.setState({
            votesToSkip:e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleGuestCanPauseChange(e){
        this.setState({
            guestCanPause:e.target.value==='true'?true:false
        })
    }
    handleRoomButtonPressed(){
       const requestOptions={
           method:'POST',
           headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}, //recomendado isso em mtd post mas nem smpr é obrgtr
           body:JSON.stringify({
               votes_to_skip:this.state.votesToSkip,
               guest_can_pause:this.state.guestCanPause //obs->o nm dss fields tm q ta igual q ta n srdr/mdl
           })
       }
       fetch('api/create-room',requestOptions).then(response=>response.json())
       .then(data=>console.log(data))
    }
    render(){
        //grid usa flexbox p alinhar elmnts n hrzntl ou vrtcl,por pdr qnd dfn grid assim,v ser container e alinha coisas
        // numa estrtr d cln,o spacing fl o espç entre os elmnts d grid,1 sgnfc 8px e 2 16px
        return (<Grid container spacing={1}> 
            <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
              <Typography component='h4' variant='h4'>
                  Create A Room
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
              <FormControl component='fieldset'>
                  <FormHelperText>
                      <div align='center'>Guest Control of Playback State</div>
                  </FormHelperText>
                  <RadioGroup row default='true' onChange={this.handleGuestCanPauseChange}>
                      <FormControlLabel value='true' control={
                         <Radio color='primary' label='Play/Pause' labelPlacement='bottom'/>
                        }/>
                      <FormControlLabel value='false' control={
                         <Radio color='secondary' label='No Control' labelPlacement='bottom'/>
                        }/>
                  </RadioGroup>
              </FormControl>
              <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
                  <TextField required={true} 
                             type='number'
                             onChange={this.handleVotesChange} 
                             defaultValue={this.defaultVotes} 
                             inputProps={{min:1,style:{textAlign:'center'}}}
                            />
                  <FormHelperText>
                      <div align='center'>Votes Required to Skip Song</div>
                  </FormHelperText>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
                  <Button color='primary' variant='contained' onClick={this.handleRoomButtonPressed}>
                      Create A Room
                  </Button>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} align='center'>
                  <Button color='secondary' variant='contained' to='/' component={Link}> 
                      Back
                  </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>)
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText'
```

or

```
import {FormHelperText} from '@material-ui/core'
```

see https://v4.mui.com/api/form-helper-text/.

Comment: ohhhhh thanks SO MUCH!!! it worked ,I don't give you a like just because everytime I try it stack overflow gives me a modal saying "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: You should still be able to accept the answer. You are the only one who can.